# Differential or intersection of islands of 2D polygons in different layers

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, geometry, mesh, polygon

I have a 2D layer/section containing the 2D polygons colored in shades of **green**.
I have another layer containing the 2D polygons colored in shades of **blue**.

[image: Two layers of 2D polygons]

I intend to figure out how different are the two layers. Maybe extracting the layers differential. Can anybody provide an **algorithm**, **library** or a **hint**? I took a look at [CGAL](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/packages.html), but not quite sure which package to try out.

Comment: "how different the two layers are" - this is a very broad statement, can you be more specific.

Comment: @pmw1234 Thanks for the good catch. I'm going to come up with a proper function.

Comment: Can you describe them a bit more. Is each layer just a soup of disconnected polygons? CGAL has boolean operations for sure but its not clear if that's what you want. Also describe the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CGAL, there is the [Arrangement package](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/index.html#Chapter_2D_Arrangements) that allows to build a topologically valid planar partition given a set of segments, and the [Regularized Boolean Set-Operations](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Boolean_set_operations_2/index.html#Chapter_2D_Regularized_Boolean_Set-Operations) that provides boolean operations between polygons.